# enable/disable html hyperlink of parent element from iFrame (For given structure) using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to disable/enable hyperlink for few click events which may occur on pages,which are being loaded in [iframe name="homeFrame"] ,event can be button click.

Div leftNav contains navigation link which do get loaded in [iframe name="homeFrame"].

I want to know,how can I disable/enable those links from page loaded in Iframe.

Please guide me for the same! Thanks!

**HTML Code:**

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="frmHome">

<div id="MainDivH"  style="background-image:url(images/headerbg.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-x; width:100%;">
  <div id="header" style="width:984px; font-family:Calibri; padding-left: 37px;">
  </div>

  <div id="divNavigation" class="divNavigation" style="padding-left:37px; float:left;">

     <div id="countrydivcontainer" style="float:left" >
     <div id="divProduct" style="padding-bottom:20px; padding-top:20px; position:static;">

     </div>

    <div id="PCcontentWrapper">
      <div class="leftNav" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;">
          <ul id="topUL"> 
            <div  background:url(images/pcnav.png) left top no-repeat;">TEST LINKS</div>
            <li style="text-align:center;"><a id="202" name="test1" class="test" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:top.frames['homeFrame'].location='TestLink/link1.php'" target="homeFrame">&nbsp;Test 1</a></li>
            <li style="text-align:center;"><a id="204" name="test2" class="test" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:top.frames['homeFrame'].location='TestLink/test2.php'" target="homeFrame">&nbsp;Test 2</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    <!--End of left nav-->  

  <div class="pcContener" id="pcContener" style="float:right; padding-left:20px;">
         <iframe name="homeFrame" id="homeFrame" scrolling="no" style="height:750px; float:right; width:758px; font:Calibri; overflow:hidden;">


        </iframe>
   </div>

   </div>
</div>  <!--End of PCcontentWrapper-->  
</div>   <!--End of divNavigation-->     
</div>   <!--End of MainDivH-->
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: This sound like an XY-problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - please tell us about X!

Comment: you want the page in your iframe to disable the links of your parent page?

Comment: @Abhidev: Yes, I'm trying same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is have a js function in your parent page that will disable the links.

**parent page js...Updated**

```
function disableLinks(){
   var links = $('#topUL a');
   links.each(function(){
      $(this).click(function(){
          return false;
      });
   });
}
```

call the parent js function from your iframe

**iframe page js**

```
window.parent.disableLinks();
```

Comment: Thanks! Function is getting called,but links are still clickable!

Comment: Its returning [Object object]

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(condition)//write ur conditions here
         disableLink();
    else
       showLink();



    function disableLink()
            {

            document.getElementById('Link1').disabled=true;
            document.getElementById('Link1').removeAttribute('href');    
            document.getElementById('Link1').style.textDecoration = 'none';
            document.getElementById('Link1').style.cursor = 'default';
            }

   function showLink()
            {
            document.getElementById('Link1').disabled=false;
            document.getElementById('Link1').href = "somepage.html";
            document.getElementById("Link1").style.textDecoration = "underline";
            document.getElementById("Link1").style.cursor = "hand";
            }
```